# What is the name for the non-extension part of a filename?

Tags: file-systems, files, industry-standard, file-extension

Given the file path:

```
/some/path/abc.txt
```

The *filename* is "abc.txt", and *extension* is "txt".

What is the "industry standard", **unambiguous** name for the "abc" part?

---

For reference, in both java's older `java.io` and newer `java.nio` libraries, *filename* means "abc.txt", and there is no term (ie the library APIs don't support) for the "abc" part.

Comment: Microsoft used ["FilenameWithoutExtension"](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.path.getfilenamewithoutextension%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) as the term in the .NET framework.

Comment: The best term I've come across is "file name without extension". It doesn't exactly roll off the tongue though.

Comment: filename = name + extension

Comment: Would be nice if the unambigious name also worked for `filenames.with.several.periods` and `.dotfiles`. But I doubt you´ll even find a standard one for Windows only (the main platform that cares about extensions).

Comment: @RemcoGerlich I would expect and happily accept `"filenames.with.several"` from `filenames.with.several.periods` and `""` from `.dotfiles`

Comment: I don't see the question as opinion-based. It is asking for a standard term.  The answer is that there is none.  People may provide their opinion of what the term should be, but it wouldn't be an answer to the question.

Answer (score 7):

I believe that's just called the "filename" as well, which makes thing fairly [confusing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Filename):

> Discussions of filenames are complicated by a lack of standardisation of the term. Sometimes "filename" is used to mean the entire name, such as the Windows name c:\directory\myfile.txt. Sometimes, it will be used to refer to the components, so the filename in this case would be myfile.txt. Sometimes, it is a reference that excludes an extension, so the filename would be just myfile. Such ambiguity is widespread and this article does not attempt to define any one meaning, and indeed may be using any of these meanings. Some systems will adopt their own standardised nomenclature like "path name", but these too are not standardised across systems.

If it's important, you'll have to make sure you clarify exactly what "filename" you're talking about.

Comment: You haven't answered the question. You've only offered reasons to support it being asked.

Comment: @Bohemian Actually, it confirms that this question is purely opinion-based. There is no standard term. What you're asking for just doesn't exist.

Comment: @Bohemian You are assuming the question has an answer. For my part, I call the pieces "filename" and "filename extension". So I actually agree with FirstLastName's answer.

Comment: @ThomasOwens that's what I was afraid of :) I use "non-extension part of the filename", but surely someone somewhere must have named this thing. How about "file stem"

Comment: Actually some consider the path part of the file name.